# How to keep text file contents in same Format after replacing a string

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have a text file with the contents:

```
love 
test
me
once
```

My Java program replaces the word "love" by "liverpool". But the text file loses its format and becomes like this:

```
Liverpool  test me once
```

All the strings appear on a single line.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Replace_Line {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            oldtext += line + " ";
        }
        reader.close();
        // replace a word in a file
        // String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("boy", "Love");

        // To replace a line in a file
        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("love", "Liverpool");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
                "C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File.txt");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Any help to keep the file format the same and just replace the string.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You lose the line breaks while reading like this:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    oldtext += line + " ";
}
```

To fix it, you should replace the code inside the loop with

```
oldtext += line + "\n";
```

But be aware of the fact, that reading a file line by line and concatenating each line with `+=` is very inefficient. You can do so when learning Java, but never in any production code. Use a `StringBuilder` or some external libraries to handle IO.

Answer (score 1):

When you read by lines, you're removing all line breaks and then replacing them with a space.

```
oldtext += line + " ";
```

Needs to be

```
oldtext += line + System.lineSeparator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
oldtext += line + " ";
```

by

```
oldtext += line + "\n";
```

Note that this will transform the new line characters (which could be \r or \r\n) by a \n though. Also note that concatenating using the + operator in a loop is very inefficient because it produces a whole lot of large throw-away STring instances. You'd better use a StringBuilder or StringWriter.

Why don't you simply read the whole file as a single String, and then call replaceAll and rewrite everything. See [Guava's method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#toString%28java.lang.Readable%29) or [commons-io method](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)